# GLFW | What is a frame?

Tags: glfw

[Here](https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/quick.html#quick_swap_buffers) I was reading about buffers and found such text:

> When the entire frame has been rendered, the buffers need to be swapped with one another, so the back buffer becomes the front buffer and vice versa.

And also this

> The swap interval indicates how many frames to wait until swapping the buffers, commonly known as vsync.

The question is: what is a frame? And how does it differ from buffer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is a frame?

This word comes from the film industry, where the images on a reel of film are referred to as [frames](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Film_frame).

> In filmmaking, video production, animation, and related fields, a frame is one of the many still images which compose the complete moving picture.

---

> And how does it differ from buffer?

A [buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_buffer) is a region of computer memory allocated for storing data. The image that is generated by rendering a scene is stored in a buffer.

While a still image can be represented by a single buffer, an animation requires many buffers to be presented in a sequence (like a reel of film). Each buffer in that sequence can be considered a frame when given this context.